# advance pdf viewer installing error in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Inside Flutter I am making a  exam test flutter in which , I am adding test page where 70% screen is of pdf and 30% to select option of question but to show pdf on screen I am using `advance_pdf_viewer` but on  instating plugin. I'm getting version solved error as follows

> Because advance_pdf_viewer <1.2.0 depends on flutter_cache_manager
> ^1.1.3 and advance_pdf_viewer >=1.2.0 <1.2.1 depends on path_provider
> ^1.6.11, advance_pdf_viewer <1.2.1 requires flutter_cache_manager
> ^1.1.3 or path_provider ^1.6.11. And because advance_pdf_viewer ^1.2.1
> depends on path_provider ^1.6.24, advance_pdf_viewer <2.0.0 requires
> flutter_cache_manager ^1.1.3 or path_provider ^1.6.11. And because
> advance_pdf_viewer >=2.0.0 <2.0.1 depends on flutter_cache_manager
> ^3.0.2 and advance_pdf_viewer >=2.0.1 depends on flutter_cache_manager
> ^3.3.0, every version of advance_pdf_viewer requires
> flutter_cache_manager ^1.1.3 or >=3.0.2 <4.0.0 or path_provider
> ^1.6.11. And because exammers_final depends on cached_network_image
> ^2.5.1 which depends on flutter_cache_manager ^2.1.0, every version of
> advance_pdf_viewer requires path_provider ^1.6.11. So, because
> exammers_final depends on both path_provider ^2.0.11 and
> advance_pdf_viewer any, version solving failed. pub finished with exit
> code 65

My `Pubspec.yaml`

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^0.13.4
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  rflutter_alert: ^2.0.4
  get: ^4.6.3
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  bloc: ^8.0.3
  flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  sembast: ^3.2.0
  provider: ^6.0.3
  cached_network_image: ^2.5.1
  bottom_navy_bar: ^5.6.0
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.3
  html: ^0.15.0
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.5
  firebase: ^9.0.3
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.19
  firebase_core: ^1.16.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.3.3
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.1.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.5.3+1
  readmore: ^2.2.0
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.3.1
  share_plus: ^4.0.10
  image_downloader: ^0.31.0   
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
```

Comment: try doing `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get`

Comment: Thanks for your response , but the error is still the same

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your packages are clashing with each other, so what you could do is remove the version specification and then do your flutter pub get, so flutter resolves with the correct versions that would work together properly, then you can go to your `pubspec.lock` to get the proper versioning that would not cause an error.

In this case the package you want to install without a version is

```
advance_pdf_viewer
```

Then you can get it's workable version from you `pubspec.lock`.

I just checked the documentation for

```
advance_pdf_viewer
```

and they installed it like this

```
advance_pdf_viewer: any
```